# Inseting pretrained network to pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am new to deep learning as well as pytorch. I have got the following code (siamese network) working with pytorch:

https://github.com/KrisG04/Siamese-using-PyTorch/blob/master/Siamese-networks-medium.ipynb

Now I would like to replace the CNN with a pretrained network (trained on places dataset): https://github.com/CSAILVision/places365

How do I do this using pytorch?

Comment: Are the architectures and the number of parameters the same?